# Escaping quotes in json string

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, asp.net, json

```
JavaScriptSerializer s = new JavaScriptSerializer();
result = s.Deserialize<Hashtable>(data);
```

Error is thrown if data is

```
"{a:\"\"test\" 123\",b:\"hello\" }"
```

No error is thrown if data is

```
"{a:\"test 123\",b:\"hello\" }"
```

How do I adjust the data string so that no error is thrown even when there are quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That shouldn't happen but try single quotes?

```
"{a:\"'test' 123\",b:\"hello\" }"
```

Or this:

```
'{a:"\"test\"" 123",b:"hello" }'
```

Comment: I need test to be in double quotes though.

Comment: Then put the whole thing in single quotes.

    `'{a:"\"test\"" 123",b:"hello" }'`